# Unity Rigidbody2D "Is Kinematic" bug, how do I solve?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For some reason my unity seems to be having a gravity to the right, this problem I found out its due to "RigidBody 2D" and can "Mostly" be fixed by using Is Kinematic option, but when I do it, it stops falling (gravity disabled).

Here is a demonstration of whats happening:
http://youtu.be/C7TbOxv8CJE

What is going on? whats the reason of this happening? How can I fix it?

OBS: I don't have any code pushing the GameObject to the right, If I simply spawn a new Sprite GameObject and add RigidBody 2D with a Collider (any) this already starts..

Comment: Is it colliding with a Raycast?

Comment: Just add a debug message inside OnCollisionEnter2D

Comment: Just made it, it only enter collision when it collides with the ground I made, but from the moment I play its not touching anything and still goes to the side...

Comment: Are you using AddForce anywhere?

Comment: What about your Gravity settings? `Edit > Project Settings > Physics 2D`, default is x=0 and y=-9.81

Comment: OMGtechy, nope i'm not using it, @Leosori, its this default value as you showed, just checked it.

Comment: Save and close unity. Start up unity and reopen the project... Sometimes unity glitches and does random weird things.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your Physics settings. In **Edit->Project Settings->Physics** and make sure that the Gravity direction is (0, -9.81, 0).

If that is all fine, I'm not sure what would cause it... But what you could do is make your own "artificial" gravity.

You could have your player be kinematic and then in it's FixedUpdate:

```
rigidbody.AddForce (new Vector3(0, -9.81f, 0));
```

Hope this helps!